# method to prepare string for a sql command

Tags: c#, sql

I need to create a string method that takes in a string and
escapes it so that it can be used in a database SQL query, for example:

```
"This is john's dog" ==> "This is john''s dog"
"This is a 'quoted' string" ==> "This is a ''quoted'' string"
```

I want my method to look something like this:

```
string PrepareForSQLCommand(string text)
{
    ...
}
```

Anyway, I don't know all of the characters that need to be escaped in SQL query.
I am not sure what the best approach is to do this, or if there is some 
existing robust built-in stuff to do this in C#.

Apologies for not mentioning this earlier: I DO NOT HAVE THE OPTION TO USE PARAMETRIZED QUERIES.

Ted

Comment: Don't prepare - do the right thing - use **parametrized queries** right from the start. Don't try to *escape* your string - you'll forget something - for sure - just don't do it - use **parametrized queries** and all your worries go away!

Comment: Have you ever heard about parameters? No need to escape anything. It's db engine job's.

Comment: You should not have to do this if all your input parameters use bind parameters.

Comment: `I don't know all of the characters that need to be escaped in SQL query`.  Basically nobody does.  Especially considering each DB will have a slightly different set of possible vulnerabilities, many of which aren't nearly as straightforward as a simple find/replace.  That's why such functions just don't exist; anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger Warning. This answer is in response to the following statement:

> I do not have the option to use parametrized queries.

Please do not up-vote this answer and please don't accept this as the correct way of doing things. I don't know why the OP cannot use parametrized queries, so I am answering that specific question and not recommending this is how you should do this. If you are not the OP, please read the other answer I have given. Also, please bear in mind the above constraint before down-voting. Thanks.

End of trigger warning!

For Microsoft SQL Server (the answer is different depending on the server) you will need to escape the single quote characters.

```
'
```

But before you escape these characters, you should reject any character not on your white-list. This is because there are lots of very clever tricks out there and white-list validation is more secure than simply escaping characters you know are bad.

```
Regex whiteList = new Regex("[^'a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
query = whiteList.Replace(query, "");
```

For example, this would remove `[` and `]` characters, and ';' characters. You may need to adjust the regex to match your expectations as this is a very restrictive white-list - but you know what kind of data you are expecting to see in your application.

I hope this helps. Feel free to check out the OWASP website for more details on security and if you can find a way of using parametrized queries you'll sleep all the better for it.

Answer (score 9):

The usual way to do this would be to use a parametrised query as part of a SqlCommand.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyCol = @param", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", "This is john's dog");
```

The framework then ensures safety for you, which is less error-prone than trying to work out all of the possible injection attacks for yourself.

Comment: haha, I just about to comment that you should be using `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", "This is John's dog");`.  + 1 for beating me to the punch.

Comment: Err, you may want to make it more clear in your example that this results in a 'constant' value - that is, parameterized queries don't usually allow _tokens_ and related items (ie `SELECT`, column names, table names, `ORDER BY`, etc) to be changed.  This also has to do with optimization possibilities.